# What shows you the package you can install to get a command?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, xfce

I have noticed on other Ubuntu machines when you don't have Maven and you try `mvn` it tells you to install `maven` or `maven2`. This does not happen on my xfce, how do I enable it?

Comment: works fine for me in a terminal running bash.

Comment: I installed a minimal ubuntu machine on my Chromebook, of course it works for you :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package, appropriately, is called [`command-not-found`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/command-not-found). The integration with `bash` for this package is part of the `bash` package itself, and unless you modified `/etc/bash.bashrc`, should work if you have this package installed.

If you're using zsh, then add to `/etc/zshrc`:

```
. /etc/zsh_command_not_found
```

Comment: muru, that file does not exist..can you recheck ?

Comment: @heemayl hmm, yes, the code from `bash_command_not_found` is not included because it's now in `bash.bashrc`. <http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/command-not-found/trusty/view/head:/debian/rules#L41>

Answer (score 4):

[muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/653084/216503) is right that the package is called `command-not-found`. It basically provides a `python` script `/usr/lib/command-not-found` that actually does the main job.

But the messages that you get in Ubuntu is actually defined by a function that actually exploits `command-not-found`'s properties. Its called `command_not_found_handle` and resides in `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

```
$ type -a command_not_found_handle 
command_not_found_handle is a function
command_not_found_handle () 
{ 
    if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
        /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1";
        return $?;
    else
        if [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
            /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1";
            return $?;
        else
            printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" 1>&2;
            return 127;
        fi;
    fi
}
```

Because of the above function we get different error messages in different cases :

```
$ svn
The program 'svn' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install subversion

$ foobar
foobar: command not found
```

Lets check :

```
$ /usr/lib/command-not-found svn
The program 'svn' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install subversion

$ /usr/lib/command-not-found foobar
foobar: command not found
```

As you does not have the `command-not-found` package enabled, you are basically satisfying the following snippet of `command_not_found_handle` function every time :

```
printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" 1>&2;
return 127;
```

Hence you are getting the following every time :

```
$ svn
svn: command not found

$ foobar
foobar: command not found
```

In a nutshell, you can install the `command-not-found` package and then add the function (if not there already) mentioned above to the file `/etc/bash.bashrc` (for all users) or `~/.bashrc` (for only you).

Comment: I did not have to modify my bash files to get it to work. Thank you for the explaination!